# Reduce in call volume

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, calls, volume-control, samsung-galaxy-note

I'm using Jelly Bean on my Samsung Galaxy Note. Plus I'm running Ultimate Rom v5.1 as mu ROM. The problem is minimum In-Call Volume is too high even though I have reduced it.

How can I reduce that in call volume than the minimum level?

Comment: You could try with an equalizer app (some phones have this pre-installed). Or check the playstore for one of the many volume boosters (search for [volume](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=volume&c=apps) will bring up a lot), though they are normally intended to *raise* the volume above the limits, some might also *lower* it below, I didn't check all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to noise cancellation was on during a call. I turn noise cancellation off now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading that increasing the volume to the max then decreasing it again to minimum seems to work

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can you throw in some reference (that you have been reading) to make the answer more credible?